# How to copy same named files from one location to another location number of times using linux command?

Tags: linux, cp

---

I have the following tree struture.

```
sl_top
|       |-- Pinmux_Formal_checklist
|       |   |-- Pinmux_Formal_checklist.config
|       |   |-- Pinmux_Formal_checklist.html
|       |   `-- rev1
|       |       |-- rev1.config
|       |       `-- rev1.html
|       |-- checklist10
|       |   |-- checklist10.config
|       |   |-- checklist10.html
|       |   `-- rev2
|       |       |-- rev2.config
|       |       `-- rev2.html
|       |-- checklist13
|       |   |-- checklist13.config
|       |   |-- checklist13.html
|       |   `-- rev2
|       |       |-- rev2.config
|       |       `-- rev2.html
```

Here checklist 13 and checklist 10 have same file name and which am copying .html files to Another location.How can i save the both copies using linux command.

Command which i have tried?

```
find . -name '*.html' -exec cp -prv '{}' 'projects/html_files' ';
```

Obatined output:

```
rev1.html
rev2.html
```

Expected output:

```
rev1.html(Pinmux_Formal_checklist.html)
rev2.html(checklist10)
rev2.html(checklist13)
```

Note:In bracket it should show the respected directory name

Answer (score 2):

If this writes the cp commands you expect, remove the `echo` from the line:

```
find . -name '*.html' -exec /bin/sh -c 'file="{}"; echo cp -prv "$file" "projects/html_files/${file##*/}(${file%/*})"' \;
```

Comment: the above command is just printing in the terminal none is copied to destination location. @Philippos

Comment: Exactly, that's for safety. But if it's printing the commands you expect, remove the `echo` as I wrote; than it will really be copying

Comment: It throws error for me as no such file directory.But am there in respected directory @Philippos

Comment: Doesn't the message include the path name that was not found? Was the path in the `echo`ed `cp` command correct?

Comment: yes everything is correct @Philippos