# How to copy all .html files from location to another location n number of times using linux?

Tags: linux, files, find

Consider the following directory :

```
ga900a
`-- ga900a
    |-- digital_top
    |   |-- Block_Physical_design_checklist
    |   |   |-- Block_Physical_design_checklist.config
    |   |   |-- Block_Physical_design_checklist.html
    |   |   `-- rev1
    |   |       |-- rev1.config
    |   |       `-- rev1.html
    |   |-- Synthesis_checklist
    |   |   |-- Synthesis_checklist.config
    |   |   |-- Synthesis_checklist.html
    |   |   `-- rev1
    |   |       |-- rev1.config
    |   |       `-- rev1.html
    |   |-- Timing_analysis_checklist
    |   |   |-- Timing_analysis_checklist.config
    |   |   |-- Timing_analysis_checklist.html
    |   |   `-- rev1
    |   |       |-- rev1.config
    |   |       `-- rev1.html
    |   |-- digital_top.config
    |   `-- digital_top.html
    |-- ga900a.config
    `-- ga900a.html
```

My referring below link i had used the same command:

```
find . -name '*.html' -exec /bin/sh -c 'file="{}"; cp -prv "$file" "/home/all_projects/import_html_files"' \;
```

The above command lists only the following files:

```
ga900a.html
Bloc_Physical_design_checklist.html
Synthesis_checklist.html
Timing_analysis_Checklist.html
digital_top.html
rev1.html
```

The above command displays only one rev1.html appears only once.But my query is i should print all .html files even if it occurs with same name multiple times.

[reference link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374121/how-to-copy-same-named-files-from-one-location-to-another-location-number-of-tim)

But my expectation is as follows:

```
ga900a.html
Bloc_Physical_design_checklist.html
Synthesis_checklist.html
Timing_analysis_Checklist.html
digital_top.html
rev1.html
rev1.html
rev1.html
```

Comment: for me it works fine, when replacing `cp` with `echo` printing output like ./.PyCharmEdu30/config/courses/Introduction to Python/lesson2/task3/task.html
./.PyCharmEdu30/config/courses/Introduction to Python/lesson2/task8/task.html so task.html occurs several times, of course with path prefixed

Comment: in destination can you able to see two task.html files ? @Jaleks

Comment: surely not, the second one writes over the first one, as the files are copied one over another into the same directory. How would it be possible to have different same named files in one directory? Maybe the '-r' for cp does not what you think it does...

Comment: but i like to bring same named files to be copied multiple times into destination.Is there any possible way to dow ith linux command that is what my question .@Jaleks

Comment: It's possible to *copy* same named files;however it's not possible for multiple files with the same name to reside in a single directory - so the previous files will get successively overwritten. You can add the `--backup=numbered` option to `cp` to add a distinguishing suffix each time there is a name conflict.

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to have several files with the same name in one directory. You might only consider to let `cp --backup=numbered` add automatically backup files with ascending numbered suffixes for the former existing file(s) with the same name.